# Roomdatabase backup file showing roommaster table scribbly text

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-room, backup

I have a method in my program that backs up a room database in android studio. When I export the file, it comes out as a .txt file. However in my file, the data is all scribbly and not well structured as shown in the image below. I just want the text file to show only data from the room database table columns.

My method to backup the room database

```
   public void backupDatabase() throws IOException {
        File backupFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME + ".txt");

        if (!backupFile.exists()) {
            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile)) {
            }
        } else {
            if (!backupFile.canWrite()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("User does not have permission to write to file " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(context.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME));
             FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(BackupRestore.this, "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The .txt file does show the database in the middle, but the sqlite format stuff is unnecessary

[image]

And this is the database content which is what I am trying to show

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So all I had to do was iterate over the list of users and write each user's file to the outputstream file like this:

```
public void backupDatabase() throws IOException {
    File backupFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME + ".txt");

    if (!backupFile.exists()) {
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile)) {
        }
    } else {
        if (!backupFile.canWrite()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("User does not have permission to write to file " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    AppDatabase database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class,"InnBucks_DB").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    UserDao userDao = database.userDao();

    List<User> userList = userDao.getallusers();

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile)) {
        for (User user : userList) {
            outputStream.write((user.getId() + "\n").getBytes());
            outputStream.write((user.getUserId() + "\n").getBytes());
            outputStream.write((user.getName() + "\n").getBytes());
        }
    }


    Toast.makeText(BackupRestore.this, "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```